# Is $G$ always a split extension over Fitting subgroup under certain hypothesis?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group and $F(G)$ its Fitting subgroup. If $F(G)$ is a $p$-subgroup, is $G$ always a split extension over $F(G)$?

Comment: However, there is a double cover $B$ of the symmetric group $S_{4}$ which has order $48$, and a generalised quaternion Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ of order $16$. The Fitting subgroup $F$ of $B$ has order $8$, but is not complemented in $B$, as ite it not complemented in $S$ ( $F$ has index $2$ in $S$ but contains the only involution of $S$.

Comment: Oh, dear; confused the Fitting and the Frattini subgroups; sorry about that.

Comment: If the Frattini subgroup if $G$ is trivial, then a finite solvable $G$ does split over $F(G)$ whether or not $F(G)$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: I think $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/p^2\mathbf{Z})$ is also a counterexample.

Comment: @YCor : But it is not solvable if $p > 3.$ For non-solvable groups, any non-simple, but quasisimple, finite group $G$ is a counterexample

Comment: For those of you familiar with GAP and Magma databases, Geoff Robinson's counterexample is $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(48,28))$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson ah, indeed $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z})$ might coincide with your example (in which case $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z})$ would be no counterexample).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks for your nice counterexample and your useful comments.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Could you provide me with a counterexample for $F(G)$ being a $p$-subgroup for an odd prime?

Comment: There are such counterexamples. I will need to dig one out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been answered in the comments, but here is a summary.

There are counterexamples. One such (suggested by Geoff Robinson) is $\texttt{SmallGroup}(48,28)$, with $F(G) \cong Q_8$. A similar example is $\texttt{SmallGroup}(48,30)$, but here $F(G)$ is elementary abelian of order $8$.

You asked for examples with $|F(G)|$ odd. One such is $\texttt{SmallGroup}(648,531)$, with $F(G$ extraspecial of order $27$. A similar example is $\texttt{SmallGroup}(648,531)$, but here $F(G)$ is elementary abelian of order $27$.

In both of those last two examples, $G/F(G) \cong {\rm SL}(2,3)$, and a corresponding example with $p=5$ would not be solvable. But fortunately you have not requested an example with $p>3$.

Comment: An example with $p=5$: Let $T=Q_8*D_8$. Then $T$ has an automorphism $h$ of order $5$, and the semidirect product $T\langle h\rangle$ embeds in $Sp_4(5)$. Hence, letting $P$ be extraspecial of order $5^{1+4}$ and exponent $5$, there is a semidirect product $G=PT\langle h\rangle$. Now let $G_1=PT\langle h_1\rangle$ where $h_1$ acts on $PT$ like $h$, but $h_1$ has order $5^2$ and $h_1^5\in Z(P)$. Then $G_1$ is solvable, $F^*(G_1)=P$, but $G_1$ does not split over $P$ - a complement would have to be isomorphic to $T\langle h\rangle$, but any element of order $5$ in $N_{G_1}(T)$ centralizes $T$.

Comment: @Derek Holt@Rickard Lyons Thanks for your nice counterexamples.